# passing variable value to UIFont systemFontOfSize function

Tags: ios, uibutton, swift2, xcode7

i need to have a button with rounded corner and title label with font size proportionally to button height

i have a custom class for my button:

```
class RoundedButton: UIButton {

override func layoutSubviews() {

    super.layoutSubviews()

    layer.cornerRadius = bounds.size.height / 2.0
    clipsToBounds = true

    let size : CGFloat = (self.titleLabel!.font.pointSize*self.frame.height)/30
    self.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(size)
}
}
```

i need to set the title label font size proportionally to button height because the height of the button changes in proportion to the height of view.

if i pass the value directly the code work:

```
self.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(18)
```

but if i pass the value from variable the code not work:

```
self.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(size)
```

any idea?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your `size` definition properly.

```
let size = CGFloat((self.titleLabel!.font.pointSize*self.frame.height)/30)
self.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(size)
```